# Turning on wifi opens app in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, application-launch

Please if someone knows how to do this or if it is possible at all help me, I was wondering if there is any way i could make my laptop open a certain app everytime i turn on wifi. Thanks. All answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the task scheduler for this. First open it, then click Action > Create new task. Then add the full path of your program. Now in the Triggers tab click Add. Choose On an event from the first dropdown list. Then use:

Log: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational

Source: NetworkProfile

Event ID: 10000

In Conditions tab uncheck  “Start the task only if the computer is on AC power" if checked. Then you can use Start only if the following network connection is available to run task on specific programs.

Comment: Worked like a charm!